# Selenium downloads PDF into default folder (Downloads) but not in specified in chromePrefs

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium Java in my automation framework and trying to download PDF from Chrome, below is my code:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
        chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:");
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I specified location "C:" (for just testing purpose) but the issue is that it downloads PDFs in Downloads folder.

Also is there a way to specify name of file that I'm trying to download?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515328/how-to-set-default-download-directory-in-selenium-chrome-capabilities has a similar answer.

Comment: @arundeep-chohan as you can see my code looks almost the same but it still saves files not in specified directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, the issue was it is not recommended to use folders like: "C:" or "Desktop" or relative path, that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, it should work :**

```
String desired_path = "D:\\user\\report";
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
hm.put("download.default_directory",desired_path);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",hm);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```